# Kubernetes Inject Env Variable with File in a Volume

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

Just for training purpose, I'm trying to inject those env variables with this ConfigMap in my Wordpress and Mysql app by using a File with a Volume.

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
  namespace: ex2
data:
  wordpress.conf: |
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST mysql
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER admin
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD "1234"
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_PREFIX wp_
  mysql.conf: |
    MYSQL_DATABASE wordpress
    MYSQL_USER admin
    MYSQL_PASSWORD "1234"
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD "1"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: mysql
  name: mysql
  namespace: ex2
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3306
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  type: ClusterIP

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    app: mysql
  namespace: ex2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: mysql:5.6
          name: mysql
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: "/etc/env"
              readOnly: true
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3306
              protocol: TCP
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: wordpress-mysql
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: wordpress
  name: wordpress
  namespace: ex2
spec:
  ports:
    - nodePort: 30999
      port: 80
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: wordpress
  type: NodePort

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wordpress
  labels:
    app: wordpress
  namespace: ex2
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: wordpress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: wordpress
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: wordpress
          name: wordpress
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: "/etc/env"
              readOnly: true
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
              protocol: TCP
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: wordpress-mysql
```

When I deploy the app the mysql pod fails with this error:
`kubectl -n ex2 logs mysql-56ddd69598-ql229`

> 2020-12-26 19:57:58+00:00 [ERROR] [Entrypoint]: Database is
> uninitialized and password option is not specified
> You need to specify one of MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD and MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

I don't understand because I have specified everything in my configMap. I also have tried by using `envFrom` and `Single Env Variables` and it works just fine. I'm just having an issue with `File in a Volume`

Comment: You mounted two files into a directory in `/etc`; nothing in Kubernetes or the container would generally read back those files.  You need to use the standard Kubernetes syntax to [Define container environment variables using ConfigMap data](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data) (which involves making the variable names top-level keys in the ConfigMap).

Comment: @DavidMaze What I'm trying to do, is to use a volume like in this doc: [Add ConfigMap data to a Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#add-configmap-data-to-a-volume)

Answer (score 2):

@DavidMaze is correct; you're mixing two useful features.

Using `test.yaml`:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: wordpress-mysql
data:
  wordpress.conf: |
    WORDPRESS_DB_HOST mysql
    WORDPRESS_DB_USER admin
    WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD "1234"
    WORDPRESS_DB_NAME wordpress
    WORDPRESS_DB_PREFIX wp_
  mysql.conf: |
    MYSQL_DATABASE wordpress
    MYSQL_USER admin
    MYSQL_PASSWORD "1234"
    MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD "1"
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    app: test
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: busybox
          name: test
          args:
          - ash
          - -c
          - while true; do sleep 15s; done
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: "/etc/env"
              readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: config
        configMap:
          name: wordpress-mysql
```

Then:

```sh
kubectl apply --filename=./test.yaml

kubectl exec --stdin --tty deployment/test -- ls  /etc/env
mysql.conf      wordpress.conf

kubectl exec --stdin --tty deployment/test -- more /etc/env/mysql.conf
MYSQL_DATABASE wordpress
MYSQL_USER admin
MYSQL_PASSWORD "1234"
MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD "1"
```

> **NOTE** the files are missing (and should probably include) `=` between the variable and its value e.g. `MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress`

So, what you have is a ConfigMap that represents 2 files (`mysql.conf` and `wordpress.conf`) and, if you use e.g. `busybox` and mount the ConfigMap as a volume, you can see that it includes 2 files and that the files contain the configurations.

So, **if** you can run e.g. WordPress or MySQL and pass a configuration file to them, you're good but what you probably want to do is reference the ConfigMap entries as environment variables, per @DavidMaze suggestion, i.e. run Pods with environment variables set by the ConfigMap entries, i.e.:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#define-container-environment-variables-using-configmap-data

Answer (score 0):

I would really suggest not to use configmap for wordpress. You can use directly the official repo https://github.com/docker-library/wordpress/tree/master/php7.4/apache it has a docker-entrypoint.sh which you can use to inject the env values from the deployment.yaml directly or if you use vault that works perfectly too.